# approximate identity- common compact set

Tags: real-analysis, approximation-theory, smooth-functions

let us consider a sequence of smooth functions with compact support $\phi_n$, which approximate Dirac measure at zero, such that $\int_{\mathbb{R}}\phi_n(x)\,dx=1$. Okay, I can consider something like that, but can somebody give me some example of such sequence? I know it will be something like $\phi(x)=\exp(-x^2)$ but could somebody write me it down really precisely? If not, I have one question: do this sequence has one common compact support or it changes with the change of $n$?

Comment: If they have a fixed compact support they won't form an approxiamate identity. For construction of such sequences see Rudin's FA.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In general an approximation to the identity just needs to be some family $\{\phi_n\}$ of $L^1$ functions with $\int \phi_n \, dx = 1$ for each $n$. In many applications we want these $\phi_n$ to be 1) smooth and 2) compactly supported.

To achieve (1) your example of $\phi(x) = \frac{1}{\sqrt{\pi}}e^{-x^2}$ works, if we then set $\phi_n(x) = n\phi(nx)$. To achieve goal (2) we want to pick $\phi$ to be some bump function, usually
$$
\phi(x) = \begin{cases}
c\exp((1 - |x|^2)^{-1}) & x \in (-1, 1) \\
0 & x \not\in (-1, 1).
\end{cases}
$$
Here $c$ is whatever positive constant needed to make the integral equal to 1. Then set $\phi_n(x) = n\phi(nx)$ as above. In this case the support of $\phi$, and $\phi_n$ for all $n \geq 1$, is contained within $B(0, 1)$.

Comment: Okay, thank you very much.

Comment: Okay, thank you very much. So, coming back to general case, there exists a sequence of smooth functions with common compact support $\phi_n$ such that $\lim_{n\rightarrow\infty}(f*\phi_n)=f$, for some $f$, right?

Comment: Yup, and in fact for all $f$ (if the requirement were just for "some" $f$, we could choose $f = 0$ and any $\phi_n$ would work). But you also have to be careful in what sense you're taking the limit; see for instance Bass, Real Analysis, 3rd edition (available for free in pdf form on his website). If $f$ is in $L^p, p\in [1, \infty)$, you in general only know $f * \phi_n$ converges in $L^p$ to $f$. If $f$ is continuous, though, $f * \phi_n$ converges uniformly on compact sets. If $f \in L^p, p \in [1, \infty]$ you get a.e. convergence.